# Latex, how to “avoid” syllabify or hyphenation

Tags: sectioning, chapters, hyphenation

I've a problem with latex (I'm new with it): it hyphenates :) :) I'm writing my thesis and I don't want the hyphenation. The strange thing is the fact that when I write the `\chapter` there is no hyphenation while this happen as soon as I write a `\section` or in the same chapter!

How can I solve this problem? thanks everyone!

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside, pdf, english]{toptesi}
\begin{document}
\chapter{What is Business Intelligence?}
\paragraph{}
Since the 1990s, the socio-economic context within which economic activities are carried out has generally been referred to as the information and knowledge society. 
The profound changes that have occurred in methods of production and in economic relations have led to a growth in the importance of the exchange of intangible goods, consisting for the most part of transfers of information.
\section{Definiton and Aims of Business Intelligence}Business intelligence methodologies are interdisciplinary and broad, spanning
several domains of application. Indeed, they are concerned with the
representation and organization of the decision-making process, and thus with
the field of decision theory; with collecting and storing the data intended to
facilitate the decision-making process, and thus with data warehousing technologies;
with mathematical models for optimization and data mining, and
thus with operations research and statistics; finally, with several application
domains, such as marketing, logistics, accounting and control, fi...
\end{document}
```

Comment: There are a lot of questions concerning the hyphenation in its corresponding tag: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hyphenation

Comment: `\paragraph` should not be used as you show here, it is the 4th level section heading after chapter,section,subsection, subsubsection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you do *not* use the `babel` package, you could load the `hyphenat` package with the option `none` to suppress hyphenation *globally*:

```
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
```

The entry [Stopping all hyphenation](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-hyphoff) in the TeX FAQ lists further possibilities for suppressing hyphenation globally.

If, on the other hand, all you want to achieve is to suppress hyphenation in sectioning headers, you can achieve your goal by loading the `sectsty` package and issue the command

```
\allsectionsfont{\raggedright}
```

in the preamble.

The command `\raggedright` suppresses hyphenation and also -- as its name suggests... -- switches from full justification to flushleft/raggedright typesetting.

Comment: `toptesi` does use `babel`.

Comment: @egreg - I suspected as much. That's why I offered the additional suggestion, to use the `sectsty` package as a straightforward way to suppress hyphenation in sectioning headers.

Answer (score 3):

It might be a good idea for `toptesi` to add an option for raggedright titles, but you can add it quite easily.

In the example I added a mock word in order to see the hyphenation.

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside, pdf, english]{toptesi}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\patchcmd{\section}{\normalfont}{\doraggedright\normalfont}{}{}
\patchcmd{\subsection}{\normalfont}{\doraggedright\normalfont}{}{}
\patchcmd{\subsubsection}{\normalfont}{\doraggedright\normalfont}{}{}
\patchcmd{\paragraph}{\normalfont}{\doraggedright\normalfont}{}{}
\patchcmd{\subparagraph}{\normalfont}{\doraggedright\normalfont}{}{}

\newcommand{\doraggedright}{\raggedright}
%\newcommand{\doraggedright}{}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{english}

\chapter{What is Business Intelligence?}

Since the 1990s, the socio-economic context within which economic activities 
are carried out has generally been referred to as the information and knowledge 
society. The profound changes that have occurred in methods of production and 
in economic relations have led to a growth in the importance of the exchange 
of intangible goods, consisting for the most part of transfers of information.

\section{Definition, Fooness and Aims of Business Intelligence}

Business intelligence methodologies are interdisciplinary and broad, spanning
several domains of application. Indeed, they are concerned with the
representation and organization of the decision-making process, and thus with
the field of decision theory; with collecting and storing the data intended to
facilitate the decision-making process, and thus with data warehousing technologies;
with mathematical models for optimization and data mining, and
thus with operations research and statistics; finally, with several application
domains, such as marketing, logistics, accounting and control, fi...

\end{document}
```

With the given definition for `\doraggedright` the output is

[image]

If you switch the comment character as in

```
%\newcommand{\doraggedright}{\raggedright}
\newcommand{\doraggedright}{}
```

you get the standard behavior

[image]

#### Notes

1. The `\paragraph{}` command is not needed and it's actually wrong. Paragraphs are separated by a blank line
2. You get better readability of source code by not continuing after `\section{...}`; a blank line there helps for better reading.
3. A `\selectlanguage{english}` is necessary to get “Chapter” and not ”Capitolo”.

Answer (score 0):

As Mico says, if you turn off hyphenation you should also turn off justification. Just be aware that this will also set the paragraph indentation to 0, so you need to add that again. MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\raggedright % turn off hyphenation and justification
\setlength{\parindent}{1.5em} % set paragraph indentation
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```